# How to prevent removing text from mail destroying HTML?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a procedure that finds a certain string and removes it.

This is done through `Replace()`.

However when the incoming mail is HTML rather than plain text, most HTML features are destroyed, and the mail is plain text plus hyperlinks.

It is therefore obvious that my procedure kills something in addition to the string.

Here is my procedure:

```vb
Public Sub EditBodyCgReplace()

    'Declarations
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim DoSave As Boolean
    Dim NewBody As String
    Dim strDelete01 As String
    Dim strDelete02 As String
    Dim strDelete03 As String

    'Fill the variables 
    strDelete01 = "Diese E-Mail kommt von Personen außerhalb der Stadtverwaltung. Klicken Sie nur auf Links oder Dateianhänge, wenn Sie die Personen für vertrauenswürdig halten."
    strDelete02 = "################################################################################"

    'Work with it 
    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set obj = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If Sel.Count Then
            Set obj = Sel(1)
            DoSave = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not obj Is Nothing Then
        NewBody = Replace(obj.Body, strDelete01, "")
        NewBody = Replace(obj.Body, strDelete02, "")
        If NewBody <> "" Then
            obj.Body = NewBody
            If DoSave Then
                obj.Save
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

What can I do that this (or a similar) procedure kills the string but does not harm the HTML structure of the e-mail so that it's visual features on screen are persevered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set the plain text `Body` property. Work with the `HTMLBody` property instead.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds straightforward and logical. But where and how could I do this? Could you give a hint?

Comment: Replace Body with HTMLBody in your script.

Comment: I implemented this now (using **obj.HTMLBody** instead of **obj.Body** whereever it appears in the skript above), and indeed it did the trick. (I have other issues now, but these are not related anymore to the actual question asked here).